# Foreach Loop took more time to process

Tags: c#

I have two collections and some conditions are done using linq query. Comparing two lists and getting result from that. I have used foreach loop and linq query, the collections have 65 thousand datas, my problem is it tooks more time to process. My code is mentioned below. How to improve the performance and how to reduce the processing time. If any idea to improve the performance please share.

```
foreach (var part in quoteParts)
{                            
    var presentPart = existingPart.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PartName == part.PartNumber);

    if (presentPart != null)
    {
        int partID = presentPart.ID;
        string partNumber = Convert.ToString(presentPart.PartName);

        foreach (var quotesPart in quoteStepInProcesses)
        {
            var presentStepInProcess = existingStepInProcesses.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessId == quotesPart.StepInProcessID && quotesPart.PartNumber == partNumber); 

            if (presentStepInProcess != null)
            {
                PartProcesses.Add(new PartProcessDto
                {
                    ProcessName = Convert.ToString(presentStepInProcess.ID),
                    PartName = Convert.ToString(presentPart.ID)
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give any suggestion to how to fix this performance problem

Comment: Use a performance profiler.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? We can't give improvements based on a "make it faster" request. How fast is faster? What's the ideal performance? What's the data type and why use `Convert.ToString` instead of casting if it's an object?

Comment: Is `quoteParts` coming from a database?

Comment: Yes, the quoteParts and QuoteStepInProcesses are came from database  @mjwills

Comment: In that case, you should solve this in the database rather than in memory. Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 9):

You have at least two places where you're using `FirstOrDefault` inside a loop to locate a record. The first thing I'd try would be pre-indexing that data; for example:

```
var partsByName = existingPart.ToDictionary(x => x.PartName);
foreach (var part in quoteParts)
{
    if(partsByName.TryGetValue(part.PartNumber, out var presentPart))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and similarly with `existingStepInProcesses` via `ProcessId`. Also note that the second test in your innermost `FirstOrDefault` (`&& quotesPart.PartNumber == partNumber`) doesn't actually filter `p`, so should be moved **away** from that lookup. So: outside the first loop next to the first `ToDictionary`:

```
var processes = existingStepInProcesses.ToDictionary(x => x.ProcessId);
```

then in the innermost loop:

```
if (quotesPart.PartNumber == partNumber &&
    processes.TryGetValue(quotesPart.StepInProcessID, out var presentStepInProcess))
{
    // ...
}
```

You can *possibly* also do the same with `quoteStepInProcesses` to remove the second `foreach` - it depends on how many matches you expect. If there are multiple: maybe `.ToLookup` instead of `ToDictionary`.